# How to properly use getUpdates method from Telegram API

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram, polling

Let's say I would like to create a simple "listener" bot which will print out the result when I send the message "say *". I would imagine that it should look like this:

```py
import requests
import time

key = 'iknowthatyouarenotsupposedtodoitlikethat'

start_time = time.time()
while True:
    result = requests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{key}/getUpdates?timeout=1').json()
    if result['result'][-1]['message']['date'] < start_time: continue # Ignore old messages
    message = result['result'][-1]['message']['text'].split()
    if message[0] == 'say':
        print(' '.join(message[1:]))
        break
```

This is by no means an example of a great approach, but it should work fine :).

The problem here is that the `result` variable is filled like it is supposed to with messages from the last 24 hours, but starting with the second iteration it only receives the  one or two most distant messages, which is super weird. I have found that doing `time.sleep(.25)` after each iteration seems to fix the issue, but this looks like such a dumb fix which may not be reliable. If this is simply rate limiting, there at least should be some indication of the error, but the code is always `200` and there are no indications of the problem.

The same happens when you try doing the request by directly inserting the link into the browser and start mashing `F5`, which is obvious, but it is easier to see what I am talking about this way.

After looking into the documentation I have found that this issue may be caused by short polling which is "only recommended for testing purposes", but this should be fixed by the `timeout` argument which I have.

I don't know how to further approach this issue, so maybe there a solution that I am not seeing?

Comment: A while true will constantly fetch Telegram, why would you do that?

Comment: @0stone0 To get a response from the user as soon as they send a message

Comment: @0stone0 It’s how it works: The response will be finished when an update is received or when the timeout exceeds.

Answer (score 0):

Using `time.sleep(25)` would break the long polling mechanism, because the call to `getupdates()` is performed every 25 seconds. Instead, you have to specify the `timeout=25` (not 1) property inside the api call to `getupdates()`. That way telegram will keep the connection open and respond immediately when there is an update, while waiting 25 seconds before answering if no updates are present (and so before your next api call). Another important parameter of `getupdates()` is 'offset' (the last `message_id` checked): do not compare by date to discard oldest updates, that way telegram will ALWAYS return ALL the updates in the 24h. Using offset instead, telegram will delete those already checked, so `getupdates` will answer immediately ONLY if there is a NEW update. The following is a sample code in laravel (the loop is finite, just for test purposes), but you can adapt to use with curl:

```
STATIC $lastOffset = 0;
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    $updates = Telegram::getUpdates(['offset' => $lastOffset,'timeout'=>25]);
    $cnt = count($updates) ;
    if($cnt != 0) {
        $lastOffset = $updates[$cnt-1]['update_id'] + 1;
        dump($updates[$cnt-1]['message']['text']); // Assuming the messages are of text type!
    }        
    else dump("Timeout reached with no updates");
}
```

Remember that the server could answer an error too, if the connection is lost, for example. So you have to check for void update list and errors too, before handling the update list.